# How to use cursors in libdbi - postgresql

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm connecting to a large postgresql database(300 million records) with libdbi and perform a `SELECT *` query, then show the result line by line. I'm getting full swap and memory so it seems `autocommit` is enabled and it loads the whole result set in the memory. Is there any option to disable autocommit or at least hold cursors after commit like `ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT` in java? I didn't find any option for `dbi_conn_set_option` to do it. here is my code:

```
dbi_conn conn;
dbi_result result;
int64_t id;

dbi_initialize(NULL);
conn = dbi_conn_new("pgsql");

if (conn == NULL)
{
    printf("connection error.\n");
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

dbi_conn_set_option(conn, "host", "127.0.0.1");
dbi_conn_set_option(conn, "username", "postgres");
dbi_conn_set_option(conn, "password", "123456");
dbi_conn_set_option(conn, "dbname", "backup");

if (dbi_conn_connect(conn) < 0)
{
    printf("could not connect to database.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

result = dbi_conn_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl");
if (result)
{
    while (dbi_result_next_row(result))
    {
        id = dbi_result_get_longlong(result, "_id");
        printf("This is _id: %ld\n", id);
    }

    dbi_result_free(result);
}

dbi_conn_close(conn);
dbi_shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to autocommit.

The solution to the out-of-memory problem is indeed to use a cursor to fetch N results at a time as opposed to all results in one step.

`libdbi` doesn't provide an abstraction for SQL cursors, so it needs to be done with SQL queries.

The documentation's [page on FETCH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html) has a complete sequence of queries in its example that shows how it's done. You need to call these queries with libdbi in C with two loops: an outer loop calling `FETCH N from cursor_name` until there's nothing left to fetch, and an inner loop processing the results of that FETCH, just like your current code processing the results of the `select *` itself.

Comment: At least when using Java/JDBC the use of server-side cursors **is** related to the autocommit setting, because "*The backend closes cursors at the end of transactions, so in autocommit mode the backend will have closed the cursor before anything can be fetched from it*"